# .Net Framework too big?

Tags: .net, diskspace

Every time a new feature like WPF comes along, it's added to the .Net Framework. Do you ever worry about disk space on the clients computer? Should I?

Comment: .NET 4 has a cut-down 'client profile' just for this. But it's part of the OS footprint really, and not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worry about it - but only a little. Although storage space is incredibly cheap nowadays, ansd cheap enough today to buy a duplicate storage device to backup onto, there are costs due to "bloat".

As the amount of stuff increases, you have to load more of it into memory - using up RAM, but also taking more and more time to read it off the disk and pass it over the memory bus. And, as the RAM gets used, parts of the data read from disk is swapped out, meaning even more time writing, and then even more time reading when you want it back! Its a vicious circle of slowness, disk grinding and finger-tapping as you try to use your computer. (just look to examples like Outlook or Visual Studio with a few plugins like Resharper to see what I mean).

So, although its not a big deal individually, the idea that "disk space / RAM is cheap so use as much as you like" is not good, you should worry about the bloat in your apps, and try to make your apps more efficient and therefore more responsive.

Of course, this applies double for laptops. triple for netbooks, and quintuple for mobiles.

Perhaps we should worry about disk space after all!

Comment: tribble? obviously not, now fixed :)

Answer (score 5):

In my experience in .Net, if the client's computer has issues with the size of .Net, there are probably deeper problems to worry about, than if your program will work.

Considering that most recent versions of Windows install .Net by default, or in a service pack, I dare say there's very little to worry about.

Lastly, if you're an ASP.Net developer, your own .Net framework folders will be rather bloated by the "Temporary ASP.Net files" folder that gets created, so it'll be rather smaller for a user.

Answer (score 2):

No. Disk space is probably the cheapest component of computers these days (in $/MB).

Answer (score 2):

If anything, the .net framework is getting smaller, .net 3.5 was really, big ( 200+MB ) .net is smaller at 48MB nevermind the fact that you can use the client profile 29MB

Here is a [link to a post by Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx) about the .net 4 fm size and related info

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Mindlessly including code "because it can be theoretically useful one day, maybe" leads to code that's bloated and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

No.  And if you want to target .NET you have to accept the size anyway so why worry about it?  More important is the user having the correct version and a seamless install that doesn't require much user interaction.  Non-tech users don't know or care about .NET and just want to use the application.  So anything that makes them wait will be seen negatively.